# GitHub - how do I replace files in repo with new ones?

Tags: github

I have a Jekyll blog that I have hosted on GitHub Pages. What I am trying to do is update the existing repo with my new files. I wasn't sure what to do because I didn't want to delete the repo, and I didn't want duplicate files (old and new), just my new files from my new directory.

My question is (giving another breakdown first)-

- I have deleted the old directory **locally** that included my hosted GitHub Pages Jekyll blog files.
- I re-made a new Jekyll blog **locally** under the same name as my previous directory (using *jekyll new username.github.io *)
- I still have my old blog files in my jekyll blog repo on GitHub.

I would like to delete the old files (but not the repo), and update that repo with my new blog files. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a normal git repo, you should be able to link it with the upstream repo in the usual way (further details to come in an edit).

Jekyll/Github docs: https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages

You should be able to run `git push` from your new repo, and it should just work. If not, hopefully a `git pull` beforehand should solve it. If not, post a comment and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just posted a question in response, but figured it out! Thanks Jesse!